Is the documentation of NestWhileList[] incorrect? [Edit: it is not]
The documentation of NestWhileList indicates the following:
NestWhileList[f,expr,test,m]


supplies the most recent m results as arguments for test at each step.

whereas
NestWhileList[f,expr,test,m,max]


applies f at most max times.

However, this is not the behavior that I observe. For instance:
NestWhileList[Plus[1, #] &, 1, True, 5] returns {1, 2, 3, 4, 5} -- expected would be to exceed the iteration limit (infinite loop).
while
NestWhileList[Plus[1, #] &, 1, True, 1, 5] returns {1} -- expected would be {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}.
What is even stranger is that:
NestWhileList[Plus[1, #] &, 1, True, All] also returns {1} -- expected would be another infinite loop.
I have a hard time believing that the documentation for such a fundamental function could be wrong, so I am hesitant to submit a bug report.
Am I missing something obvious here?

NestWhileList[Plus[1, #] &, 1, True, 1, 5] returns {1}, but
NestWhileList[Plus[1, #] &, 1, True&, 1, 5] returns {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}
Is the key that True does not return True?

True is not a valid test function (it doesn't return True as you've said), so NestWhileList exits as soon as it manages to apply the test once. If you ask for 5 elements to be supplied, it needs to first generate 5. If you ask for All it can apply the test already after the first.

I see, thank you.
I cannot believe that I never encountered the difference between True and True& before. (Or perhaps I have, and I couldn't figure out what was wrong.)
Perhaps I should delete the question [?].
